# Oracle optimise SQL query - Multiple Max()

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table where first I need to select data by `max(event_date)` then need to 
filter the data by `max(event_sequence)` then filter again by `max(event_number)`

I wrote following query which works but takes time.

Here the the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.stuid,
                   a.prog,
                   a.stu_prog_id,
                   a.event_number,
                   a.event_date,
                   a.event_sequence,
                   a.prog_status
   FROM table1 a
   WHERE a.event_date=
       (SELECT max(b.event_date)
        FROM table1 b
        WHERE a.stuid=b.stuid
          AND a.prog=b.prog
          AND a.stu_prog_id=b.stu_prog_id)
     AND a.event_seq=
       (SELECT max(b.event_sequence)
        FROM table1 b
        WHERE a.stuid=b.stuid
          AND a.prog=b.prog
          AND a.stu_prog_id=b.stu_prog_id
          AND a.event_date=b.event_date)
     AND a.event_number=
       (SELECT max(b.event_number)
        FROM table1 b
        WHERE a.stuid=b.stuid
          AND a.prog=b.prog
          AND a.stu_prog_id=b.stu_prog_id
          AND a.event_date=b.event_date
          AND a.event_sequence=b.event_sequence
```

I was wondering is there there a faster way to get the data?
I am using Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a simple `row_number()` or `rank()`:

```
select t1.*
from (select t1.*,
             rank() over (partition by stuid, prog, stu_prog_id
                          order by event_date desc, event_sequence desc, event_number desc
                         ) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: It works:) I could not up vote you as I have less than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try rephrasing your query using analytic functions:

```
SELECT
    stuid,
    prog,
    stu_prog_id,
    event_number,
    event_date,
    event_sequence,
    prog_status
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY studio, prog, stu_prog_id
                     ORDER BY event_date DESC) rnk1,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY studio, prog, stu_prog_id, event_date
                     ORDER BY event_sequence DESC) rnk2,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY studio, prog, stu_prog_id, event_date, event_sequence
                     ORDER BY event_number DESC) rnk3
    FROM table1 t
) t
WHERE rnk1 = 1 AND rnk2 = 1 AND rnk3 = 1;
```

Note: I don't actually know if you really need all three subqueries there.  Adding sample data to your question might help someone else improve upon the solution I have given above.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried this query but it does not work as expected(exclude some prog). I will try to upload the data.

Answer (score 0):

As being an `Oracle 12c` user, you can use

```
[ OFFSET offset { ROW | ROWS } ]
[ FETCH { FIRST | NEXT } [ { rowcount | percent PERCENT } ]
    { ROW | ROWS } { ONLY | WITH TIES } ]
```

syntax as :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.stuid,
                a.prog,
                a.stu_prog_id,
                a.event_number,
                a.event_date,
                a.event_sequence,
                a.prog_status
  FROM table1 a
 ORDER BY event_date DESC, event_sequence DESC, event_number DESC
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

where `WITH TIES` clause is not needed for your case, since you're looking for `DISTINCT` rows, and `OFFSET` is not needed either, since starting point is just the beginning of a descendingly ordered columns. Even, using the keyword `ROW` as `ROWS` is optional, even for the case of plural rows such as `FETCH FIRST 5 ROW ONLY;
                 ^^ --> ROWS without S`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d4e26d09d099c76878172040829cda2a)</kbd>

Comment: I think this will return only one row or number of rows but not first row from each group.

Comment: @Tejash No, there's no problem per each group, since each column is restricted among each other step by step. Consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6d4a787a609854c04945f9c189be665f).   `event_sequence` is filtered by `event_date`, and `event_number` is filtered by `event_date` and `event_sequence`.

Comment: There will be max `event date` for each `stuid, prog and stu_prog_id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple records with `EVENT_DATE, EVENT_SEQUENCE, EVENT_NUMBER` as max respectively then in Tim's solution, Use `DENSE_RANK` or use the following to fetch the `exact max` and compare with `original column data`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.STUID,
    A.PROG,
    A.STU_PROG_ID,
    A.EVENT_NUMBER,
    A.EVENT_DATE,
    A.EVENT_SEQUENCE,
    A.PROG_STATUS
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            A.STUID,
            A.PROG,
            A.STU_PROG_ID,
            A.EVENT_NUMBER,
            A.EVENT_DATE,
            A.EVENT_SEQUENCE,
            A.PROG_STATUS,
            MAX(A.EVENT_DATE) OVER(
                PARTITION BY A.STUID, A.PROG, A.STU_PROG_ID
            ) AS MAX_EVENT_DATE,
            MAX(A.EVENT_SEQUENCE) OVER(
                PARTITION BY A.STUID, A.PROG, A.STU_PROG_ID, A.EVENT_DATE
            ) AS MAX_EVENT_SEQUENCE,
            MAX(A.EVENT_NUMBER) OVER(
                PARTITION BY A.STUID, A.PROG, A.STU_PROG_ID, A.EVENT_DATE, A.EVENT_SEQUENCE
            ) AS MAX_EVENT_NUMBER
        FROM
            TABLE1 A
    ) A
WHERE
    A.MAX_EVENT_DATE = A.EVENT_DATE
    AND A.MAX_EVENT_SEQUENCE = A.EVENT_SEQUENCE
    AND A.MAX_EVENT_NUMBER = A.EVENT_NUMBER;
```

Cheers!!